# How do I properly route my signal to this BNC connector on my PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, signal, bnc

I am looking to use several of [these Amphenol BNC connectors](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/amphenol-rf/112536/1011730?utm_adgroup=Coaxial%20Connectors%20%28RF%29&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping_Product_Connectors%2C%20Interconnects&utm_term=&utm_content=Coaxial%20Connectors%20%28RF%29&gclid=Cj0KCQiA2-2eBhClARIsAGLQ2RnXC8eDiWKrnPCmXDFilI7-6qM3wBvl_owwMCNXnsk2HTInHMGFyysaAnbXEALw_wcB) on my PCB.

When I look at the datasheet, my instinct tells me that I should route my signal to pin 1 and then  ground the rest.
Here is the PCB symbol and the datasheet. Neither have good indicators regarding what to do with each pin.
[image: PCB Symbol]
[image: Datasheet]

How do I know what to attach to each pin? Are some of the pins just used as mounting support and are supposed to be left isolated?

Comment: The choice of which pin on the schematic is signal is completely arbitrary.  Select one and then assign that pin to the center one on the datasheet.

Comment: Do you have a PCB footprint? It should show you how they are mapped.

Comment: That's a horribly unhelpful PCB symbol.

Comment: Feel free to learn how to make schematic symbols -- even if you're the only consumer of the schematic, but _especially_ if it'll be used by other people, a symbol that uninformative will plague you.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I am sorry, I was not clear enough. The middle pin is pin 1, and the outer four pins are pins 2-5. Can I simply route my signal to pin one? If that is the case, do I ground pins 2-5? @timwescott

Comment: @te4gan yeah, you route the signal in pin 1. But first check if the pcb program your are using has map the pin 1 of the symbol to the pin 1 of the footprint. Same as the rest of the pins. Somewhere in your pcb program there is this information. And of course check if the pin 1 of the footprint is the center pin… The rest is ground pins. These connectors needs strong connection with the ground. And follow the impedance rule that you calculate for your signal trace.

Comment: Yes, signal goes to the center pin and ground goes to the outer ones (whatever the numbering is).  However "simply" is a loaded word: t's a BNC connector which implies an impedance-controlled circuit.  So whether just routing signals and grounds willy-nilly will work depends on what you're doing.  If it's not critical, and not radio frequency, high speed or high power -- yes, you can just connect up the traces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how.

[image]

The centre pin is to be soldered to its trace and the common / mounting pins to the ground plane.

Here's a view of a similar [Amphenol](https://docs.rs-online.com/1ec2/0900766b80e02cc9.pdf) connector.

[image]

The common / mounting pins are integral to the metallic body.

Comment: Note that for this particular connector, the signal trace must *not* be on the same side that the connector is placed; otherwise, you're relying on soldermask for insulation, which is never a good idea. It has to be on the opposite side or an internal layer.

Comment: Yes, it's on the opposite side.

Comment: Can you cite the figure?  How are we to know that this isn't just an assumption on your part.

Comment: The figure, depicting the relevant part of the PCB, was prepared by me. My answer has been edited to include a view of a similar Amphenol connector and a link to its drawing,

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how inconvenient getting it wrong is, using your intuition is usually not the best practice.

That drawing provides you with no information about connections.  It "looks like" the center pin goes to the center BNC conductor.  Whether that's correct, or whether all the other pins are connected to BNC shield, is very hard to know.  You also have no real way of knowing how the pins are numbered.

So, there are a number of approached.  One is simply to find a different part that actually gives you a real datasheet instead of this part.  Another would be to order what you need, and get out your multimeter when they arrive and figure it out prior to making your PCB.  A third option would be to find the part elsewhere and see if they offer better documentation.

https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Amphenol-RF/112536?qs=zdwcGW1B%2Fd%252Bu7oZ8rPhfSg%3D%3D shows that the center pin is in fact, pin 1, when you look at their "ECAD" model, taking away that part of the guesswork.  It also looks like all the perimeter pins are connected to BNC shield.